# How to display data to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have used `JTextField` and it is working well, but I need the data that I want to display not to be edited by the user. 
Is there any other way than using `JTextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uneditable `JTextField` (`textField.setEditable(false)`). Now, one would probably ask: "And why not JLabel?". Because, copying text/result from `JTextField` is always easier than retyping it from `JLabel` (note that `JLabel` is not focusable). Plus, uneditable `JTextField` can listen for events like `FocusEvent`

Answer (score 2):

use JLabel

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("this is uneditable");
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your specific needs.

- You can call `setEditable(false)` on your `JTextField`. It will still be able to gain focus, but the text cannot be edited.
- You can use a `JLabel` to simply display the text with no interactivity or focus gaining.
- You can use a `JButton` to display the text if you need a single action interaction.

See [this](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html) to help you choose the best component for your needs.